# How can I download files from a folder in Artifactory with a specific property using JFrog CLI?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

Using [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Download,CopyandMoveCommandsSpecSchema) (v1.48.1) I want to download the contents of a folder from an on-premise Artifactory instance (EnterpriseX license 7.41.7). The folder in question is on a specific sub-path in the Artifactory repo and has a specific property by which I can identify the folder.

The overall repo structure is a follows:

```
product-repo
    |-- develop
    `-- releases
            |-- ProductX
            `-- ProductY
                   |-- build01 [@release_ready = false]
                   |-- build02 [@release_ready = false]
                   `-- build03 [@release_ready = true]
                          |-- x86
                          |    `-- program.exe
                          |-- x64
                          |    `-- program64.exe
                          `-- common
                               `-- README.txt
```

All `buildXX` folders are identical in terms of content. All `buildXX` folders have a property named `release_ready` which is `true` for `build03` and `false` for the other two folders.

In the example above, I want to download the folder `build03` including all its contents because this folder is on the `releases/ProductY` path of the `product-repo` repository and has `release_ready` = `true`.

I have devised a [file spec](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Using+File+Specs) for this task:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "product-repo",
          "path": {"$match":"*releases/ProductY*"},
          "type": "folder",
          "@release_ready": {"$eq": "True"}
        }
      },
      "recursive": "true",
      "target": "some/folder/on/my/disk/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using JFrog CLI to search this folder (`jfrog rt s --spec myfilespec.json`) works like a charm - as expected, Jfrog returns the folder `build03`.

However, when I try to download the folder using
`jfrog rt dl --spec myfilespec.json` Jfrog CLI only creates the folder structure releases/ProductY/build03 at the target path but never actually downloads any files. The exact log output is as follows:

```
 Log path: C:\Users\myuser\.jfrog\logs\jfrog-cli.<date>.log
{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

With the log file containing just the following lines:

```
[Info] Searching items to download...
[Info] [Thread 2] Downloading procduct-repo/repeases/ProgramY/build03/
[Info] [Thread 2] Creating folder: releases\ProgramY\build03
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from above explanation, it gives a clarification that you have the property and value applied on a the folder only but not on the artifacts under it.
Your first AQL query results only the folder name.
Since it reveles the folder name, would it be feasible to pass the above result in the download command as below.

```
jfrog rt dl "product-repo/releases/ProductY/build3/*" --flat=false /some/folder/on/my/disk/
```

Comment: After many more experiments I came to the conclusion that you are indeed totally right with your suggestion: Splitting my request in two separate requests is really the only way to do what I want to do using Artifactory. It's a shame that Artifactory properties cannot be transitive. :(
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `"type": "folder"` line from the spec file. I suspect this is what causing only the folder to be created but the actual files not to be downloaded.

You may also avoid using AQL, and use the `"pattern"` and `"props"` fields, making the spec file a bit more straight forward:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "product-repo/releases/ProductY*",
      "props": "release_ready=true",
      "recursive": "true",
      "target": "some/folder/on/my/disk/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Prostagma! Unfortunately, your suggested file spec also only returns 

[Info] Searching artifacts...
[Info] Found 0 artifacts.
[]

I think the problem is that the individual artifacts do not have the ```release_ready``` property - only the folder has that property and it seems like JFrog's search cannot work with properties "on the way", i.e. properties do not seem to be transitive.

If I add the release_ready property to individual artifacts, your query does indeed find themm.